# Where can I find the "Work Offline" option in SSIS location

Tags: ssis

I was having trouble finding the work offline option in SSIS. I was receiving a suggestion from visual studio that I should try to set `Work Offline` to off.  I am going to answer this myself.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are on the `control flow` tab and right click and you will see the option to work offline or not.

They took away the dropdown of SSIS in my version of visual studio (Installed September 2021). I know it might seem simple but it took me some time to find it and the internet was not helpful in my searchings.